# a4j commandlink not working after rerender

Tags: ajax, richfaces, jsf-1.2, ajax4jsf

The text with id=txt is inserted outside the commandlink after rerendering.
And therefore the link is broken. A refresh of the page gets it back.
Could somebody please help?

```
<h:form id="frm">
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{myBean.currentId}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.selectListA}" />
        <a4j:support event="onchange" action="#{myBean.changeSomething}" 
            reRender="priceGroup,idLink" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <h:panelGroup id="priceGroup">
        <a4j:commandLink id="idLink">
            <h:outputText id="txt" value="#{myBean.someValue}" />
        </a4j:commandLink>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Have you tried to reRender only the panelGroup? `reRender="priceGroup"`

Comment: @jmrodrigg   Yes, I have; with no success. I have made I workaround for my problem. Instead of ajax rerendering, I put a valueChangeListener on the selectOneMenu and a form submit. Then it works. But I'm still interested in a solution for the actual problem.

Comment: Yes, it's a bit strange because I tried your code (without the `action` tag) and it worked for me. Try adding `ajaxSingle="true"` in the `a4j:support` tag.

Comment: do you really need to set the link text by using a nested `h:outputText`? did you try do this: `<a4j:commandLink id="idLink" value="#{myBean.someValue}"/>`